# Pygame Sound File Crashing IDLE

Tags: python, audio, background, pygame

I'm trying to use Pygame's background music player (pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3'), pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 45.0)) to play the background music, but when I run the module, the run window stops responding almost immediately. I do have a stop in my program, at the end, and I have the mp3 in the same folder as the python file, and the FPS is limited. I'm pretty sure the code is right. I can't think of anything else besides just plain computer suckiness that could be going wrong.

Comment: You could try with an ogg file. `Be aware that MP3 support is limited... Consider using OGG instead.` Then you'll know if the problem is the file and pygame's limited support.

Comment: Code is always helpful ;) I did it with an mp3 file a while back, I  dont have the implementation at hand though, otherwise I would have given you an example. Might be able to write it later today. Is the path for the mp3 file correct?

Answer (score 0):

Using mp3 files for sound in Pygame isn't very good. If you want background music use a free audio converter (Audacity, perhaps?) and convert that music file into an OGG file. Another thing you need to consider is that you should remember to put that sound file in the same folder/ directory as your Python/Pygame script. Also, you don't necessarily need a channel to play music.

```
beep1 = "beep1.wav"
beep2 = "beep2.wav"
beep3 = "beep3.wav"
beep4 = "beep4.wav"
beep_list = [beep1, beep2, beep3, beep4]
beep = random.shuffle(beep_list)
pygame.mixer.music.load((beep_list[1]))
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

This is the code I used make it beep every time a ball hit the sides of a wall.  Perhaps you could edit it like this:

```
bgm = "backgroundmusic.ogg"
pygame.mixer.music.load((bgm))
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

NOTE: .Wav files are recommended for sound effects, because WAV files get a little bigger when its more than a few seconds long.